# Geometrical meaning of generalized Dehn twist on $T^*\mathbb{S}^n$.

Tags: symplectic-geometry, contact-topology

Can anyone explain a geometrical meaning of generalized Dehn twist on $T^*\mathbb{S}^n$?.

Thanks, advance.